# Dynamic Programming : Timus Online Judge 1119 Metro

Tags: c++, recursion, nan

I am trying to do the problem http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1119 on Timus Online Judge. 
However, for some strange reason the recursive function doesn't work. If I print just the final value returned it prints : "-nan". When I print its's rounded form it prints a garbage value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#define min(x,y) ((x<y) ? (x) : (y))
using namespace std;
int x,y;
float dp[1001][1001];    //for memoization
bool d[1001][1001];      // for storing whether diagonal movement is possible or not
float solve(int x,int y) {
    if (dp[x][y]!= -1.0)
        return dp[x][y];
    if (x == 0 && y == 0)
        return (dp[x][y] = 0.0);
    if (x == 0 )
        return (dp[x][y] = y*100);
    if (y == 0)
        return (dp[x][y] = x*100);
    float ret;
    float r1,r2,r3;
    r1 = 100.0 + solve(x-1,y);
    r2 = 100.0 + solve(x,y-1);
    ret = min(r1,r2);
    if (d[x][y]) {
        r3 = solve(x-1,y-1);
        r3 = r3 + 141.42;
        ret = min(ret,r3);
    }
    dp[x][y] = ret;
    return ret;
}
int main() {
    cin >> x >> y;
    int k;
    int d1,d2;
    cin >> k;
    memset(dp,-1.0,sizeof dp);
    memset(d,false,sizeof d);
    for (int i=0;i<k;i++) {
        cin >> d1 >> d2;
        d[d1][d2]=true;
    }
    float dist = solve(x,y);
    int ans = dist;
    if (dist - ans > 0.5) {
        ans++;
    }
    cout << ans << endl;    // Prints a garbage value
}                           // cout << dist << endl prints "-nan"
```

Here's the ideone link : http://ideone.com/6C2WjR

Comment: `for some strange reason the recursive function doesn't work.` Have you debugged your program?  Also, `memset(dp,-1.0,sizeof dp);` This does not do what you think it does.  Set the array the old fashioned -- use a loop, or better yet use C++ and use `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: Yes I debugged it whole on paper. With all the recusrion trees. memset was the problem. Thanks !

Comment: `Yes I debugged it whole on paper`  If the issue was the double values, you should have seen it right away.  When we say "debug", it doesn't mean just on paper.  Run the program using your debugger, and immediately you should have seen that `dp` had bad values from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memset(dp,-1.0,sizeof dp);` doesn't do what you think, use `std::fill` or `std::fill_n` instead.

or simply a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> dp(1001, std::vector<float>(1001, -1.f));
```

Comment: That worked. Could you additionally please explain, what does memset exactly do ? When to use it and when not ?

Comment: See [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) for more detail. As you can see `memset` is not type safe, whereas `fill` and `fill_n` are.

Comment: @g33kyaditya The `memset` function takes whatever memset deems as `-1.0` is in binary, and copies byte by byte this particular byte pattern to the address you give.  Note that the description is low-level.  At the very least, you shouldn't use `memset` to set floating point arrays, as the interpretation of `-1.0` to memset may be totally incompatible with an actual `-1.0` used by `float` or `double`.  As you can see, this is what happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
memset(dp,-1.0,sizeof dp);
```

This line doesn't work for doubles and float data types. so instead of memset, use

```
  float dp[1001][1001]={0};
```

and hence check for `if(dp[x][y]!=0)return dp[x][y];`
I hope this works.